# Use STM32L4xx dual bank mechanism for software upgrade?

Tags: arm, stm32

I am wondering if using the dual bank boot mechanism to implement my software update mechanism on STM32 is the right way to do. My worry is that in Level 2 Read Protection (which I assume is the final "production" setup), I understood switching from one bank to another for the boot is not possible.
Do you know if this dual bank mechanism is really intended for software update in the field ? And what about this Read Protection level ?
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

STM32 is pretty flexible in using its memory blocks. Banks doesn't not have much limitations it is the blocks that it work with. Level 2 Read protection is up to block level as well. So what you can do is half of the bank 1 you can use for bootloader and another half is for application and bank 2 completely for application. This way you can utilize maximum memory for application.